# Azure logic app error while decoding EDIFACT

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, edi

I'm trying to parse this EDIFACT flat file (from wikipedia) in the Azure Logic App as an exercise before moving on to the actual data, since they are very similar.

```
UNB+IATB:1+6XPPC:ZZ+LHPPC:ZZ+940101:0950+1'
UNH+1+PAORES:93:1:IA'
MSG+1:45'
IFT+3+XYZCOMPANY AVAILABILITY'
ERC+A7V:1:AMD'
IFT+3+NO MORE FLIGHTS'
ODI'
TVL+240493:1000::1220+FRA+JFK+DL+400+C'
PDI++C:3+Y::3+F::1'
APD+74C:0:::6++++++6X'
TVL+240493:1740::2030+JFK+MIA+DL+081+C'
PDI++C:4'
APD+EM2:0:1630::6+++++++DA'
UNT+13+1'
```

my integration account has an EDIFACT agreement, I don't know what type of transaction this is (Or the actual data) I can't finish the agreement in the Send / Receive settings. I have a data dictionary but I'll need to create the schema by hand, which I'm also unsure of how to do.

The error I receive in the logic flow is the following:

```
"body": {
        "errorMessage": "Error: 1 (Miscellaneous error)\r\n\t46: Character set not supported\r\n\r\n
        Error: 2 (Field level error)\r\n\t
            SegmentID: UNB\r\n\t
            Position in TS: 1\r\n\t
            Data Element ID: UNB1.1\r\n\t
            Position in Segment: 2\r\n\t
            Position in Field: 1\r\n\t
            Data Value: IATB\r\n\t
            12: Invalid value in data element\r\n\r\n",
        "statusCode": "BadRequest"
    }
```

Using the EDIFACT example found above, what would I need to do in my Azure account to finish parsing this  small example in the logic app?

Comment: can you share us a preview for your application actions that you use and the level that the exceptions appears ? is this from the first actions "Request" or after ?

Comment: @HoussemDbira the actions used before the Decode EDIFACT action are simple get file content triggers which get the content of the flat file to the decode EDIFACT action, the exception appears in the output of the decode EDIFACT message action.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Encoding of your file to UTF-8 , if the content already not encoded try get it encoded UTF8 from the source.

```
The EDIFACT connector supports only UTF-8 characters. If your output contains unexpected characters, check that your EDIFACT messages use the UTF-8 character set.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-edifact

Comment: The encoding of the file is UTF-8.

Comment: so as mentionned you need to get the content as UTF-8 from the source , this the safest way to keep original format of data.